# Virtual script not found, may missing <script lang="ts"> / "allowJs": true / jsconfig.json.volar

Tags: typescript, vue.js

[image]

The image showing the blue squiggly lines indicates an error in my footer component in VueJs (TypeScript template).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This issue came up in my Vue project, using typescript template. To solve the problem above, go to the **tsconfig.json** file, under the **compilerOptions** object-property, add:

```
"allowJs": true
```

Comment: or just remove ```//``` before ```"allowJs": true``` in the tsconfig.json file

Comment: Interestingly, the issue also comes up when _not_ using the typescript template. In this case, see [Habib Mac's answer](/a/74590966/1532478)

Comment: FYI I scaffolded a Vue project with `create-vue` and needed to add it to `tsconfig.app.json` instead of `tsconfig.json`.

Answer (score 61):

1. Just in case, for anyone who use Volar in VS Code, just run command <kbd>Ctrl/Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> type **Volar** > **Reload Project** and the warning will go away.
2. The more correct way (even if you are not using typescript), as others pointed out is to create **jsconfig.json** file in your project's root folder:

   ```json
   {
      "compilerOptions": {
        "allowJs": true
      }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thnak you very much!

Comment: solved for me 

Comment: where exactly should I run this in VS code?

Comment: Just press Ctrl+Shift+P > type "Volar" > choose "Reload Project"

Comment: ad2) It should be jsconfig.json, not jsonconfig.json

Comment: Nothing of that worked for me, it's just a temporary fix, it always come back, or I will need to reload volar every single time I create a new Vue file

Answer (score 14):

I added an empty `jsconfig.json` file to the root directory of my project, and the "problem" went away.

Comment: I am not using TypeScript but I was still getting the error. Adding a `tsconfig.json` file didn't make sense. Luckily, this worked great. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

This error occurs when a `.vue` file is missing a `lang` declaration. Add the following to your component file.

```
<script setup lang="ts"></script>
```

It will tell vue-tsc to treat the file as typescript so you do not have to set  `"allowJs": true` in your `tsconfig.json`

Answer (score 2):

This happens because typescript is complaining there is no `lang="ts"` in your script setup.

Go to tsconfig.json file usually at the bottom of folder structure on your IDE, then add this code.

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this error in a Vue project that utilizes JavaScript (not TypeScript). I simply added  in the script section of the component where the error occurred, and that resolved it.

If you're using TypeScript, use  instead.

I don't recommend placing the setup inside your script tag () unless necessary. Setup should only be used for specific cases, as it can impact the functionality of your code or component.